# Show 1/|x|^d is not Lebesgue integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm looking to show that $\frac{1}{|x|^n}$ is not integrable on the subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $|x|\geq 1$. It's easy to do on $\mathbb{R}$, and I think I need to apply Fubini's theorem for the general case, but not sure how to do so in n-dimensional space. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Via some computation and Tonelli's theorem, we have for measurable $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, \infty]$ that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\,dx = \int_{S^{n - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(r\omega)r^{n - 1}\,dr\,dS(\omega),$$
where $\,dS$ is "surface measure" on $S^{n - 1}$. Now you can plug in $f(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^n}\chi_{\{x : |x| \geq 1\}}$ and compute it's integral.

Comment: What is the relation with this and the coarea formula?

Comment: I am struggling to find a good reference to “surface measure” and how to apply it in an integral like yours. How did you derive this?

Comment: @FShrike The measure $dS$ above is the standard measure on embedded manifolds that people have been using to measure "lengths" of curves, "areas" of surfaces, etc. For a reference, see "Measure Theory and Integration" by Michael Taylor. Theory of embedded manifolds is in Appendix B. The surface measure is defined in chapter 7, and the exercises give some applications, like computing $m_n(B(0, 1))$.

Comment: As I lack any resource to a teacher or a textbook, I made up a proof of all this having seen this this morning, and asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4303423/815585). Is this loosely along the right lines of Mr Taylor's book?

Comment: @FShrike No it isn't. You seem to be focused on spheres, but the "surface measure" gives you a measure on any $m$-dimensional $C^1$ embedded manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I recommend you use a measure theory book to guide your study. You can find the pdf of Taylor's book on Libgen. Maybe he will send you the pdf if you ask him.

Comment: @FShrike The construction of the surface integral is presented here by Taylor on pages 135-140 here: https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf . The only difference from the presentation in his measure theory book is that in this analysis book he hasn't introduced measure theory, so he can only integrate continuous functions with compact support. In 3.2.12, let $f$ be a characteristic function of a Borel set and that is the definition of the surface measure (at least locally).

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. Clearly what I did was not at all similar to what Taylor is doing; was my proof nevertheless ok?

Comment: @FShrike I think you mean $S_r^{n - 1} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| = r\}$. The proof seems right, as long as you can prove (1) and (2).

Comment: Yes I did mean equality - my bad - the inequality was a typo. Good thing I didn't rely on it in the proof! Thanks for all your help